# How to compare 2 mysql table with a primary key in

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare 2 table with same primary key. For example:

```
Table A:
--------
ID, Oder_ID

Table B:
--------
ID, Value
```

```
 SELECT ID, Oder_ID FROM Table A WHERE Oder_ID= $d[1];
```

& want to find ID from Table A & then want to retrieve data from Table B using ID. Any suggestion please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables,

```
SELECT b.*                         -- will give you all the columns from TableB
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.Order_ID = $d[1];
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: that's the whole code.